# Virtual Reality without source code access is it possible

Tags: c++

Hey is it possible to make a pc game that has no access to source code to the community support virtual reality.... I need answers tonight.......

More in depth I need to know how to make a game that has no access to the source code make it support virtual reality so this means i have no source code of that game example game "fear pc from monilith" it has no source code to the community so how do you do it......

Comment: Source code from community? You mean API? Why do you want to make something from scratch if someone already did it before you? It's just a waste of time.

Comment: @John Nay it is not entirely clear what you're asking, do you want to know how to add Virtual Reality support to an existing game that you do not have the source code for?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I run third-party games on a VR device without access to the game's source code?

There are already tools out there (like VorpX) that can intercept low-level rendering calls and replace them with modified rendering calls to show a VR-display-compatible image. I haven't personally tried them out, and it seems like the VR quality can vary between games, but the answer to "is it possible" should be **yes**.